# Can't get wifi to work on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking

I installed Ubuntu last night and during the installation the wifi was working, but I didn't connected to a network at first. When I went back to connected to a network it just showed my wireless card name and no networks but I installed Ubuntu any way

I have a hp pavilion g7 laptop
And under the terminal I did "lispci" and I see a 
Realtek rtl8101/2/6e Ethernet controller I'm not sure if that is related to the wifi card, but it's only network related thing I see.

The wifi card in my laptop is a ralink
 rt5390

Comment: Check if you don't have wi-fi disabled by your hardware switch. If you don't, open terminal and type `sudo ifconfig`. Provide the output in your question

Comment: The wifi button stays orange even if I press it (it turned white when it was on, on Windows) I don't know know if it changes at all with Ubuntu